# Android Spinner not showing up

Tags: java, android, spinner

Can anyone tell me why my spinners are not showing up? I'm doing an exercise and I don't understand why my spinners show no items at all. any suggestions?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import java.util.*;

public class Length extends Activity{

    private Spinner spi1,spi2,cmbOpciones;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.length);

    //Spinner1
    List<String> imperialunits = new ArrayList<String>();
    imperialunits.add("inch");
    imperialunits.add("foot");
    imperialunits.add("yard");
    imperialunits.add("mile");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, imperialunits);

    spi1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    adaptador.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spi1.setAdapter(adaptador);

    //Spinner2
    final String[] SIunits =
             new String[]{"km","m","cm"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, SIunits);
    spi2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    adaptador2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spi2.setAdapter(adaptador2);

    //Spinner 3
    final String[] datos = new String[]{"Elem1","Elem2","Elem3","Elem4","Elem5"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, datos);

    cmbOpciones = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.CmbOpciones);

    adaptador.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    cmbOpciones.setAdapter(adaptador3);
       }

}
```

Comment: please post your layout xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to populate the Spinners looks fine (I think),maybe your problem is on your layout xml?, but why don't you try using an array of strings instead? like [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html), plus you get to use resource values, I personally think its better not creating stuff like that at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and works perfectly. I agree, it must be something wrong in your xml file.